# gradle-jpi-plugin > NoSuchMethodError: hudson.model.Messages.ExternalJob_DisplayName()

Tags: jenkins

Using the `gradle-jpi-plugin` plugin to manage a Jenkins plugin... After upgrading the config to use Jenkins "core version" `2.7.1` (from `1.581`), and running the local server command (`./gradlew server`) I received the below stackoverflow:

#### Versions

- gradle-jpi-plugin: `0.18.1`
- jenkins: `2.7.1`
- gradle: `2.13`

#### Stackoverflow ([full](https://gist.github.com/nickgrealy/116aa5240f8a5bb65b3ec88fed3a5b77))

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: hudson.model.Messages.ExternalJob_DisplayName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at hudson.model.ExternalJob$DescriptorImpl.getDisplayName(ExternalJob.java:132)
    at hudson.ExtensionComponent.compareTo(ExtensionComponent.java:97)
    at hudson.ExtensionComponent.compareTo(ExtensionComponent.java:42)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.binarySort(ComparableTimSort.java:232)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:176)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:146)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:472)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:155)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.sort(ExtensionList.java:369)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.ensureLoaded(ExtensionList.java:289)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.iterator(ExtensionList.java:156)
    at hudson.diagnosis.NullIdDescriptorMonitor.verify(NullIdDescriptorMonitor.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:104)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:175)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:999)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
…
A thread (Jenkins initialization thread/17) died unexpectedly due to an uncaught exception, this may leave your Jenkins in a bad way and is usually indicative of a bug in the code.
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0(Native Method)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(UnixFileSystem.java:242)
    at java.io.File.exists(File.java:772)
    at hudson.util.TextFile.exists(TextFile.java:57)
    at hudson.model.UpdateSite.getData(UpdateSite.java:289)
    at hudson.model.UpdateSite.getPlugin(UpdateSite.java:349)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter.getPlugin(UpdateCenter.java:611)
    at hudson.model.UpdateSite$Plugin.getNeededDependencies(UpdateSite.java:733)
    at hudson.model.UpdateSite$Plugin.isNeededDependenciesForNewerJenkins(UpdateSite.java:800)
    at hudson.model.UpdateSite$Plugin.isNeededDependenciesForNewerJenkins(UpdateSite.java:801)
    at hudson.model.UpdateSite$Plugin.isNeededDependenciesForNewerJenkins(UpdateSite.java:801)
    at hudson.model.UpdateSite$Plugin.isNeededDependenciesForNewerJenkins(UpdateSite.java:801)
```

#### See also

- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34648

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was a bit confused by this issue, as there was no reference to an `ExternalJob` class on the classpath. In fact, the class appears to be quite old, I couldn't find any recent references to it [using grepcode](http://grepcode.com/search?query=hudson.model.ExternalJob&start=0&entity=type&n=)...

After grep'ing the local directory, I found a reference in the working directory, in a plugin which I wasn't using...

```
$ grep -r "ExternalJob" *
Binary file work/plugins/external-monitor-job/WEB-INF/lib/classes.jar matches
Binary file work/plugins/external-monitor-job.jpi matches
Binary file work/war/WEB-INF/detached-plugins/external-monitor-job.hpi matches
```

**Deleting the directory** (and re-running `./gradlew server`) fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should upgrade your "External Monitor Job Type Plugin" to latest version.Hope this helps.